# React: Why do we not need to bind context to arrow functions being used as event listeners?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Looking at the react tutorial it explains that when we set event listeners, we generally have to bind the functions context, like is done here

```
class Toggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggleOn: true};

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(state => ({
      isToggleOn: !state.isToggleOn
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

I understand this, because unless we bind context to the `this.handleClick` function we have no guarantee of what value `this` will actually hold when we call `this.setState` within the handleClick function. However, the tutorial goes on to state that we would not have to bind context to the handleClick function if we replaced
`<button onClick={this.handleClick}>`
with `<button onClick={() => this.handleClick}>`

How come the correct `this` context is automatically bound when we use an arrow function?

Comment: I think this might help if you haven't already looked. https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#why-is-binding-necessary-at-all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to but arrow functions keep context of `this` as the object that defined them where traditional function context `this` as the object that calls them. You can use normal functions as long as they don't call this or keep a reference to this with a variable link `const self = this` and use self instead of this.

Why is this the case? Because they designed it to be so.

Comment: That makes sense, Thanks!